# how to assign id to li which is been got through json

Tags: php, jquery

JS

```
   $('<td  id=' + catvalue + ''+incr+'>  </td> div id=' + catvalue + ''+incr+'').html(data.view).appendTo(tr);
             tr.appendTo(table);      
                }
```

output of td id

```
td id ="i1";
td id ="i2";
td id ="i3";
td id ="i3";
```

my  **data.view**

```
<td id='i1'>
     <div class="widget-body">
                        <div>
                          <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                            <li><a href="#" > Map</a></li>// li id='li1i1'
                            <li><a href="#" ></i> Edit</a></li>// li id='li2i1'
                            <li><a href="#"></i> Add</a></li>// li id='li3i1'
                          </ul>
        </div>
        </div>
</td>
```

now my question is how to assign id to li="li1i1" which is been got through json

```
li="li1i1"
li="li2i1"
li="li2i1"
```

Comment: What does the rest of your json object look like... is there a property that contains the anchor text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you append the data, you can do:

```
...
tr.appendTo(table);      
...
$('#catvalue ul li').attr('id', function() {
    return $(this).index()+1;
});
```

Comment: You are missing a comma !

Comment: @techfoobar if there are input types i get the same id it is not been increment it will be same id for all input types but for li i get the ids correctly

Answer (score 1):

Try this after `tr.appendTo(table)`:

```
var $table = $('table');
$table.find('li').attr('id', function () {
    return 'li' + ($(this).index() + 1) + $(this).closest('td').attr('id');
});
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Z8ZPe/)

Comment: if there are input types i get the same id it is not been increment it will be same id for all input types but for li i get the ids correctly